# как нажать на кнопку на сайте через консоль JS

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка:

```
<button data-bb-handler="confirm" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
```

Как "нажать" её через консоль?

Comment: <button data-bb-handler="confirm" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>

Comment: @Sublihim Указывайте, пожалуйста, в наименовании правки, что вы код взяли из комментария. А то при проверке вашей правки этого не видно и можно подумать, что вы добавляете отсебятину.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, я так и хотел, но когда я вошел в правку, оказалось, что код уже присутствовал в вопросе, просто не был выделен как код и поэтому посчитался разметкой. Его даже в diff почему-то не видно.

Answer (score 2):

Надо каким либо образом выбрать эту кнопку, например, через метод `document.getElementById`, где вы укажете `id` элемента. Затем вызываем метод `click`.

Но наиболее универсальный способ выбрать элемента — это `document.querySelector`, к примеру для данного случая:

```
document.querySelector(".btn.btn-primary").click();
```